# If $1, \alpha _1,\ldots,\alpha _{n-1}$ are the roots of $x^n - 1 = 0$, then $n =(1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)\cdots(1-\alpha_{n-1}).$

Tags: polynomials, roots

If $1, \alpha _1, \alpha _2, \alpha _3,\ldots,\alpha _{n-1}$ are the roots of the equation $x^n - 1 = 0$ with $n\in\mathbb N$ and $n\geq 2$, show that $$n =(1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)(1-\alpha_3)\cdots(1-\alpha_{n-1}).$$

Can someone please help me? I tried using the factors as $$(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)\cdots(x-\alpha_{n-1})$$
but it did not work. Please tell me why I could not answer.

Comment: It is to be noted that $(x - 1)|(x^n - 1)$ for all  $n$ (I suppose, but it is sure for all even $n$).

Comment: Ah...yes. I was correct.

Comment: Seems like you didn't approve an edit that came by...

Comment: Please accept edits to enhance the readability of the question

Answer (score 7):

Note that $$(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)\cdots(x-\alpha_{n-1})=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}=1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}.$$
Now substitute $x=1$ in $$(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)\cdots(x-\alpha_{n-1})=1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Shivering Soldier thanks man now I understand the n part

Answer (score 2):

Let us transform $x^n-1=0$ by $y=1-x \implies x=1-y.$
Then we get $$(1-y)^n-1=0 \implies 1-{n \choose 1}y+{n \choose 2} y^2-..+(-1)^n y^n.-1 \implies (-1)^n y^{n-1}+(-1)^{n-2} y^{n-2}+....-n=0$$
roots of this $n-1$ degree polynomial equation has roots as $y_1,y_2,y_3,...y_{n-1}$ and their product is
$$y_1 y_2 y_3 y_4 y_5 ....y_{n-1}=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{-n}{(-1)^n}=n=(1-x_1)(1-x_2)...(1-x_{n-1}).$$